# Custom message for failed assertion in playwright (using cucumber.js)

Tags: playwright, assertion, cucumberjs, playwright-test

In project I use node js 20.5.1, playwright 1.37. with cucumber 8.0.0.
I want to add own customer message if expected method return me a failed. I thought I could do it like below:

```
expect(3),"My custom message").toBeLessThanOrEqual(2);
```

And in test result I should for that step
Error: My custom message,

,but I only see

```
Error: expect(received).toBeLessThanOrEqual(expected)
```

Do you know how I could handled with that ? :)
Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: 8.0.0 cucumber version is quite old, what if switch to latest one?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I updated to the latest version and problem is still occuring :) But I created workaround  
try {
              expect.soft(3).toBeLessThanOrEqual(2);
            } catch (error) {
              throw new Error(My custom message);
            }

Comment: You are using expect from playwright or from somewhere else? Could you use: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#custom-expect-message

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom Expect Error Message:

That's how I would write it:

```
expect(3,"Custom Message").toBeLessThanOrEqual(2);
```

Note: As its not asynchronous operation, we don't need to `await` it.

Reference: ​​​​

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#custom-expect-message